# How to do function autocompletion for NaN in Matlab

Tags: json, matlab

With the new [JSON-based function signature definition](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/user-defined-tab-completions-take-2), how do I specify NaN?

E.g.

```
{
"plotRay": {
  "inputs":
  [
    {"name": "RayColor", "kind": "namevalue", "type": [["numeric"], ["char"], ["nan"]], "default": "nan"}
  ]
}
}
```

I would like to allow specification as a 3-element numeric array, as a color name (e.g. 'b'), or as NaN (or is `nan` more correct now?).

Comment: `nan` is a function that returns a 1x1 array.

Comment: @Chris, that's what I knew as well. But as of yesterday my Matlab (2018b) didn't suggest to autocomplete `NaN` in an assignment. I didn't check the docs. So Nan is still OK, right? Anyway, what should I use in JSON, as it accepts, in various contexts, both functions and values?